# What is the jQuery gem for Rails 2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to make use of jQuery in Rails 2. What is the gem needed for it?

I came to know that 'jquery-rails' can be used for Rails 3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem needed to include jQuery in rails is `gem "jquery-rails"`

For previous versions of Rails, follow the 'Manual installation' on making use of JQuery in Rails 2 here - https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery inside a rails 2.x project, instead of prototype, you will have to use [jRails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails).